# App accessing mdb file on shared folder without ms access on client

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, oledb

I've been searching online for weeks now, but I can't  find any answer  or anything related to my problem

The thing is, I have an application I made using c# to load data from an mdb file. The app runs just fine because right now, the app and mdb file (for the database, using oledb) are on the same computer and not on any shared folder. But once were ready to deploy it at the office, the app and mdb file needs to be on a shared folder, to be use by multiple users but the client/user PCs doesn't have MS access installed.

The problem is that we can't install ms access or any redistributable file (the file I've been seeing on most forums/sites I visited) on the client PCs.

The client PCs have .net 4.0

My questions are:

1. Will it work? (app and mdb file on shared folder accessed/executed by the client PC's even without any ms access or redistributable file installed on the client PCs?)
2. It it wont work that way, what options do I have for the client PCs to open and run the app and mdb file saved on a shared folder?
3. If it can't be helped, how can I compile my app with a redistributable file, lets say a .dll file that will help the client PCs to open the app without ms access installed on them? for example (app,mdb and a .dll on the same shared folder)

I really hope and thank you in advance for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an access DB in your program without the clients having MS Access installed, without any problem, if you use OLEDB.NET. A question similar to yours in answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971900/do-i-need-to-have-excel-installed-to-query-spreadsheets-using-an-oledb-provider). The answer is correct, that using JET will work without the client have office installed.
Hope this helps you!

There are some links that should get you started off using JET note that google get better results if you use the common name OLEDB:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
[How to connect to a MS Access file (mdb) using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374808/how-to-connect-to-a-ms-access-file-mdb-using-c)
http://www.dscripts.net/2009/01/20/connect-to-microsoft-access-mdb-database-using-csharp/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ybdbtte%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
[OLEDB connection to Access Database (accdb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302349/oledb-connection-to-access-database-accdb)

**EDIT:**
A comment on the answer I linked asks if JET will work with MS2010. The answer is yes, from my experience.

Comment: Thanks sir, but my app is using Ace.oledb.12 (sorry I forgot to mention that) will that still work?

Comment: @vade Oh, you didn't mention that in your question! No, Ace requires the client to have it installed. Could you convert to using OLEDB?

Comment: Do you mean, using Jet.Oledb? I'm kinda new to this stuffs so I don't know much yet about the terms. And oh, sorry I can't join you yet on chat C#, my reputation is still low, actually only at 6 right now

Comment: @vade Oh that was dumb of me! Of course you cant chat yet! Yes I mean use Jet.Oledb. Check my edits for some links to some tutorials on it. I'm no expert in it either, but I am currently working on developing an app that require a DB, so I have done quite some research.

Comment: Thanks so much sir, I'll definitely look into it

Comment: @vade. No problem, you can uprate me if it turns out I helped you! :)