# Reading xlsx file in c# using OleDbConnection throws error

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I wrote a console application to read the `xlsx` file in C# using `OleDbConnection`. It throws the following error

> The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Below is the code i have written

```
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Suganya\ColumnReport.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection();
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

string Query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, objConn);

DataTable Table = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.SelectCommand = objCmd;
dataAdapter.Fill(Table);
```

I have already performed following things to fix the issue.

1. I have installed `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe` (32 bit) and found that `ACEOLEDB.dll` is present in the following path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14`
2. Tried referring the `ACEOLEDB.dll` in the application. But it gave me the following error

   > A reference to 'ACEOLEDB.DLL' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component
3. The configuration platform of console application is of 32 Bit

Environment Details

1. Windows Server 2008 (64 bit)
2. Visual Studio 2010 ( 32 bit)
3. MS office is not installed

Checked the following links to fix the issue

1.http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/486549/Theplus-27Microsoft-ACE-Oledb-12-0-27plusproviderp
2.http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/337953/The-Microsoft-ACE-OLEDB-12-0-provider-is-not-regis

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Microsoft Office; Office installation process will copy and register the wished assemblies ('ACEOLEDB.DLL') in the GAC, or you can add the missing assemblies in your bin (application) directory or regsiter them by your self.

Comment: Won't installed the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components work? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734  Answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3971925/2258

Comment: You can use the redistributable Interop Assemblies from Microsoft this included your wished dlls.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Comment: Is "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" part of that redistributable Interop Assemblies? I still get the unregistered provider  error after adding Office.Interop.Excel to my project references.