# Error while adding aceoledb reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, oledb

I am trying to refer `ACEOLEDB.DLL` in my project but it's giving me following error:

> A reference to the "ACEOLEDB.DLL" could not be added.Please make sure
>   that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM
>   component.

I copied above dll from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14` folder.

I am completely blank why visual studio 2012 is not allowing me to refer this DLL.

Comment: dll currupt nahiye na?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593665/reading-xlsx-file-in-c-sharp-using-oledbconnection-throws-error?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Why do you need to add a reference to this library?

Comment: @Steve Actually mine is a web app hosted on azure, so I cannot install database engine on azure, So I am planning to refer the ACEOLEDB DLL in my project and deploy it on Azure

Comment: @Freelancer I dont think so, but can you please let me know how to find out its corrupted or not