# Convert xls to xlsx without interop

Tags: vb.net, excel, office-interop

I have a computer(actually several machines) on my companies network that do not have office installed. I need to develop a vb.net program that will parse information from a spreadsheet which is usually in an .xls format. I don't feel that there are many options for reading data from an .xls document without the interop. If so what are some options?

If I could even convert an .xls to .xlsx programmatically without the interop, that would be an option too. I could then use ClosedXML to parse from a xlsx. Or is there a way to read an .xls file with ClosedXML that I'm not seeing?

Any help would be great as I am having trouble finding the answer to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use com interop to read from an Excel file. You can use OleDb (although you might need to install the [office data connectivity components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255))

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb:

Public Shared Function ReadExcelWorkSheet(ByVal sheetName As String, ByVal connectionString As String) As DataTable
    Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", sheetName)
    Dim dt = New DataTable()

    Using conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Using adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                adapter.Fill(dt)
            End Using
        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Where connection string is for xlsx files:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

or for xls files:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myOldExcelFile.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES";
```

more info on the [connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/) here

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the code snippet too. I'll just have to install the Microsoft.Ace.OleDB.12.0 provider, but I think this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can read it via ADO.Net.  I'd need to see your existing code, but this should allow you to open it without Excel.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';")
```

Comment: Update: The components this uses may have to be installed separately, per this [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3971925/2258)

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, this is pretty much what I'm going to do. Appreciate the help